# Крестики-нолики на C++ (минимакс)

Tags: c++

Никак не могу найти ошибку/и. Вылетает на первом же ходе. При нажатии на клетку ставится О и вызывается функция:

> `xo[tree.move(tictac,first_play)]->setText("Х");`

move() должна возвращать номер клетки, куда ставить крестик. В ней строится дерево, которое по минимаксному алгоритму выбирает наилучший вариант.

Надеюсь, найдутся благородные люди, которые покопаются в моем ужасном коде :D

```
struct Node
{
    Tictac tictac;
    Node *nodes[9];
    int min;
};

class Tree
{
public:
    Tree();
    Tree(Tictac x);
    int move(Tictac x, bool y);
    Node* addNode(Tictac x,int i,bool xo);
    void del(); //обнулить
private:
    Node node;
    bool xo; //true - x, false - o - за кого играем
};

class Tictac
{
public:
    Tictac();
    void restart(); //обнуление
    void add(int i, int xo); //добавить -1 или 1 в клетку xo
    int checkwin(bool xo); //true - играем за Х, return 5, если выиграл, -5 - проигрыш, в любом другом случае - 0
    int empty();  //сколько пустых клеток
    void print(); //вывод arr

    int arr[9]; // -1 = X; 1 = O
};
```

И сами функции:

```
int Tree::move(Tictac x, bool y)
{
    xo = y;
    node.tictac = x;
    int move, max = -5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (node.tictac.arr[i] == 0) {
            node.nodes[i]=addNode(node.tictac,i,y);
            if (node.nodes[i]->min >= max) {
                max = node.nodes[i]->min;
                move = i;
            }

            qDebug() << endl << "Max: " << max << " Move: " << move <<     endl;
        }
        else
            node.nodes[i] = 0;
    }
    return move;
}

Node* Tree::addNode(Tictac x, int i, bool play)
{
    if (play)
        x.add(-1,i);
    else
        x.add(1,i);
    Node temp;
    temp.min = x.checkwin(xo);
    //x.print();
    int min = 5, max = -5;
    if ((temp.min == 0) && (x.empty() != 0)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            if (x.arr[i] == 0)
                temp.nodes[i] = addNode(x, i, !play);
            else
                temp.nodes[i] = 0;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (temp.nodes[i] != 0) {
                if (xo != play)
                    if (temp.nodes[i]->min > max)
                        max=temp.nodes[i]->min;
                    else if (temp.nodes[i]->min < min)
                        min=temp.nodes[i]->min;
            }
        }
        if (xo != play)
            temp.min = max;
        else
            temp.min = min;

    }
    return &temp;
}

void Tictac::add(int i, int xo)
{
arr[xo] = i;
}

int Tictac::checkwin(bool xo)
{
if ((((arr[0] == arr[1]) && (arr[1] == arr[2])) || ((arr[0] == arr[3]) && (arr[3] == arr[6]))
        || ((arr[0] == arr[4]) && (arr[4] == arr[8]))) && (arr[0] != 0)) {
    if ((xo) && (arr[0] == -1))
        return 5;
    else if ((xo) && (arr[0] == 1))
        return -5;
    else if ((!xo) && (arr[0] == 1))
        return 5;
    else
        return -5;
}
else if ((((arr[3] == arr[4]) && (arr[4] == arr[5])) || ((arr[1] == arr[4]) && (arr[4] == arr[7]))
        || ((arr[2] == arr[4]) && (arr[4] == arr[6]))) && (arr[4 != 0])){
    if ((xo) && (arr[4] == -1))
        return 5;
    else if ((xo) && (arr[4] == 1))
        return -5;
    else if ((!xo) && (arr[4] == 1))
        return 5;
    else
        return -5;
}
else if ((((arr[6] == arr[7]) && (arr[7] == arr[8])) || ((arr[2] == arr[5]) && (arr[5] == arr[8]))) && (arr[8] != 0)){
    if ((xo) && (arr[8] == -1))
        return 5;
    else if ((xo) && (arr[8] == 1))
        return -5;
    else if ((!xo) && (arr[8] == 1))
        return 5;
    else
        return -5;
}
else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Как минимум, метод `Node* Tree::addNode(Tictac x, int i, bool play)` возвращает адрес локальной переменной, которая не существует после выхода из метода. Далее это может привести к непредсказуемому поведению.
Об этом в общем то должен был сказать вам компилятор в виде предупреждения (Warning).

Т.к. приведенный код не полный (отсутствуют методы `Tictac::empty`, конструктор `Tictac`) запускать не пробовал, возможно есть какие-то ещё проблемы.